# Referencing another Rule in Material UI

Tags: material-ui

I have the following code where I need to reference another rule name to avoid style duplication in material ui. Unfortunately the rules aren't reflecting.

```
const useNavStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
        active: {
            color: 'green'
        },
        listItem: {
            borderTopRightRadius: 100,
            borderBottomRightRadius: 100,
            paddingBottom: 12,
            paddingTop: 12,
            backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper,
        },
        subListItem: {
            "&$listItem": { // I wish to copy over the properties from the above listItem rule and only add padding to it, but it isn't working.
                paddingLeft: theme.spacing(4),
            },
        },
```

How do I resolve this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Referencing a local rule name does not "copy over" other styles. It changes your selector. You will still need to apply **all** those classes to your elements, which in return will then also apply the respective styles.

```js
listItem: {
  color: 'hotpink',
},
subListItem: {
  "&$listItem": {
    fontWeight: 'bold'
  }
}
```

this compiles to

```css
.listItem-1: {
  color: hotpink;
}
.subListItem-0.listItem-1: {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

In other words, this will apply styles to an element that has both these classes:

```js
<div className={clsx(classes.listItem, classes.subListItem)}>
  hotpink and bold
</div>
<div className={classes.subListItem}>no styles at all</div>
```